# Where is my Metadata?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

So I've got an odd issue.

When you attempt to have a web-project search for a service, I receive the following error:

> An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at:
>   `http://localhost:2927/WebSite/SiteHandler.svc`. Unspecified error
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800004005(E_FAIL))

Now the odd thing about this error is if the project is located on the local drive, it vanishes.  It finds the `Metadata` and works.

But when the project resides on a Flash Drive, the above error appears.  So I did the following:

- Configured Application Pool & Site
- Gave Internet Information System Access to the Flash Drive Folder Location

Which didn't resolve the error.  I assumed it was due to inability for IIS to access the Flash Drive.  So I guess my question, is this common issue for IIS?  Can it not debug off a Flash Drive?

Or are there any other ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the root directory of the IIS site was not changed to the flash drive, and therefore, the file doesn't exist on IIS's "radar". Try going into you website settings in IIS and changing the directory to your flash drive directory.